# iPhone Fast App Switching with Objective-C++

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, multitasking, objective-c++

I'm using Objective-C/C++ and I have an Objective-C class that is a wrapper for a C++ class, are there any special concerns I need to be aware of in order to use fast app switching?

It is my understanding that the iPhone will auto-magically save state for Objective-C objects, but I'm not sure if I need to do any special work to enable support for C++ objects. My C++ class does not have any virtual functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By fast app switching you mean multitasking?

There's nothing additional you need to do - iOS 4 will handle the task suspension and resume transparently, unless you need to perform background tasks, regardless of whether you're using objective c++ or just plain objective c.

Comment: I was tracking down a bug, and it turns out it wasn't related to the C++ code. Fast app switching is multitasking on the iPhone. I'm assuming that iPhone just takes the chunk of memory that was associated with an App and puts it off to the side, unless it needs to reclaim memory.